# Unable to get input regex pattern in type="email" to work correctly

Tags: html, regex

I have the following regex pattern that I'm using to validate against email addresses in JavaScript which currently works.

```js
const match = (email) => /^("?)(?:[A-Z0-9_%+-]\.?)+[A-Z0-9_%+-]\1@(?:(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,})|(?:(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3})|(?:\[(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3}\]))$/i.test(email);
  
console.log(match('email@email.com'))
console.log(match('.22@email.com'))
console.log(match('@.com'))
```

I've been attempting to use the HTML `pattern` prop to validate against this pattern, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly.

I've tried the same pattern but I can't seem to get it to work. I've also tried unescaping the regex pattern too.

```html
<form>
  <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" pattern='/^("?)(?:[A-Z0-9_%+-]\.?)+[A-Z0-9_%+-]\1@(?:(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,})|(?:(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3})|(?:\[(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3}\]))$/'>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Currently any email address results in an incorrect pattern match. Do I need to format the regex pattern differently to support this?

Comment: Use a far simpler pattern like e.g. `\S+@\S+` and try to send an actual email to that address. Your original expression looks complicated, error-prone and not maintainable (copied from somewhere?).

Comment: I want to use the pattern in the question. What the pattern is shouldn't really matter, I'm just unsure why it's not matching in HTML where as you can do `/^("?)(?:[A-Z0-9_%+-]\.?)+[A-Z0-9_%+-]\1@(?:(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,})|(?:(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3})|(?:\[(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3}\]))$/i.test('email@email.com');`to validate the string with JavaScript.

Comment: First,  you must use `type="text"`. Else, the email validation will be done with the built-in regex. Second, `pattern='/^.....$/'` must be "converted" to `pattern='...'`  : no need for slashes on both ends and no need for anchors, the pattern is anchored by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  you must use `type="text"`. Else, the email validation will be done with the built-in regex. Second, `pattern='/^...$/'` must be "converted" to `pattern='...'` as there is no need for slashes on both ends and no need for anchors, the pattern is anchored by default.

Use

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" pattern='("?)(?:[A-Z0-9_%+-]\.?)+[A-Z0-9_%+-]\1@(?:(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,})|(?:(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3})|(?:\[(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3}\]))'>
```

If you need to make it case insensitive, add `a-z` to the character classes bearing in mind that `[A-Za-z0-9_]`  = `\w`:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" pattern='("?)(?:[\w%+-]\.?)+[\w%+-]\1@(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,})|(?:(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3})|(?:\[(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3}\]))'>
```

JS demo:

```css
input:valid {
  color: black;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" pattern='("?)(?:[\w%+-]\.?)+[\w%+-]\1@(?:(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,})|(?:(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3})|(?:\[(?:[0-9]{3}\.){3}[0-9]{3}\]))' title="Please enter the right email address." />
<input type="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Can you provide a running example?

Comment: @JamesIves Here you are.